# Use a string to filename

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to put the filename from a string, but can not.

This works well:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'httpclient'

http2 = HTTPClient.new
response = http2.get_content("http://example.com/version.ini")

response.each_line do | line |

    http = HTTPClient.new
    my_file = open('file.zip', 'wb')
    my_file.write(http.get_content("http://example.com/data.zip"))

end

puts "Done."
```

But this not:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'httpclient'

http2 = HTTPClient.new
response = http2.get_content("http://example.com/version.ini")

response.each_line do | line |
    puts line # -> file.zip
    http = HTTPClient.new
    my_file = open(line, 'wb')
    my_file.write(http.get_content("http://example.com/data.zip"))

end

puts "Done."
```

Console:

> C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize': Invalid
>   argument @ rb_sysopen - file.zip (Errno::EINVAL)
>           from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in`open'
>           from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'
>           from launcher.rb:10:in`block in '
>           from launcher.rb:7:in `each_line'
>           from launcher.rb:7:in`'

Comment: Try `my_file = open(line.to_s, 'wb')`

Comment: What's the value of `puts line.inspect`?

Comment: @axelTetzlaff It does not work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev puts line.inspect =  "file.zip\n"

Comment: @WoulfAlpha: yeah, try stripping that newline char. I see you're on windows. It might not allow that freedom with filenames.

Comment: It works now !  my_file = open(line.chomp, 'wb') Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with newline char, try stripping it.

```
my_file = open(line.chomp, 'wb')
```